# Unable to complete Apple in App purchase in sandbox mode? Payment Verification

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit, titanium-alloy, titanium-modules

I am using the Titanium Storekit module to setup in App purchases on my App. The code all seems to be working from an example so I created a test account for the app and then went into the App Store settings and changed my app store account to this new id, iPhone 4s iOS7 latest build. I entered valid credit card information and even completed a purchase to get rid of the payment verification.

In my app which is running in sandbox mode i click to make a purchase, then i login to my account and it switches to iTunes stating sandbox mode. It then asks me to verify my payment information, which i have done already in the app store, then asks for my login again. Then it just repeats the message sandbox mode, login and payment details.

I just can't get it to go through as a purchase?

I used this example for the Ti.Storekit

https://gist.github.com/dawsontoth/1448587

Comment: The account you are log gin in with is this a new one you set up purely to do the testing or your actually Apple iTunes Account?

Comment: I used an existing email address and it accepted it as a test account. I did have to create a profile etc when i applied it to my phone and agree to T&C's so it wasn't used before.

Comment: Solved it, i logged into the account under the app store in the phone settings. If I just leave that account logged out it prompts me for a login and the test login works fine. Now I just need to work out why it's saying that the purchase has been made but not downloaded yet?

Comment: +1 you should post this as answer and accept it